# Mono ARMv7 and LLVM

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ios6, armv7

I'm updating my app to ios6 and i having following problem

- building application with ARMv7 is not possible to use the flag LLVM ... (error MT3001)

My system configuration is

- MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7
- MonoTouch 6.0.0.0
- Mono 2.10.9

Reference to question: [iOS 6 Mono and backward compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508826/ios-6-mono-and-backward-compatibility)

**UPDATE**

Error is

> Could not AOT the assembly ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll (MT3001)

Verbose output

```
/Users/TEST/Desktop/Xcode_4.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  -miphoneos-version-min=3.1 -arch armv7  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Users/TEST/Desktop/Xcode_4.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -c /var/folders/_3/x0_zyy9j0r5_gg94nc3r51zm0000gn/T/tmp371fb2f4.tmp/mscorlib.dll.7.s -o /var/folders/_3/x0_zyy9j0r5_gg94nc3r51zm0000gn/T/tmp371fb2f4.tmp/mscorlib.dll.7.o
error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/TEST/Public/Progetti/AppTest/bin/iPhone/Release/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll'
  at MTouch+<CompileAssemblies>c__AnonStoreyB.<>m__E (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey36`1[System.String].<>m__34 (System.String e, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState s, System.Object l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey35`2[System.String,System.Object].<>m__32 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+ActionInvoke.Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll it's a library that i use to unzip file.

Comment: Have you installed the "Command Line Tools" in Xcode?  Under Preferences->Downloads->Components in XCode.

Comment: Install it and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Please add/pastebin the full build log, since that's where additional information is shown (you'll also want to enable verbose build output, by adding "-v -v -v" to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iPhone Build options page).

Comment: @jonathanpeppers i have installed Command Line Tools and problem persists.

Comment: @Rolf Bjarne Kvinge i have add verbose output

Comment: @Luigi: that's only a (small) part of the build output, not all of it.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've updated to ios 6.0 and one of my Apps that used SharpZip give me this error. Any new idea?

Comment: It happens when sgen is enabled, and linking is turned off. The .s file generated by llvm becomes so huge that it causes a
linking problem.
As a workaround, you can set the linker behavior to 'link sdk assemblies only'.
This is the default, and without it, the resulting application binary will be huge.